# JS/Jquery Select all images, but those that repeat just once

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to select all the images of a website

```
var images = $('img')
```

but in some websites, some images repeat, so basically what i'd like to know is

How can i select all the images in a website(repeating and non-repeating) only once.

For example, the website has

```
<img src="link 1">
<img src="link 2">
<img src="link 1">
<img src="link 3">
<img src="link 1">
```

and i wish to only select

```
<img src="link 1">
<img src="link 2">
<img src="link 3">
```

Comment: There is no way select distinct src's, you have to select them all and have and array an go pushing the src's and checking if its in the array for every image.

Comment: what it has nothing to do with CSS? Use proper tags

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet i see, thank you for the answer

Comment: @RajendranNadar dont we use css selectors when selecting elements from the DOM with $() or .getElementByXYZ ?

Comment: css selector refers to the selectors you use in a css file. Jquery uses them too, you are correct, but we dont call them css selectors. Not the best argument in the world, but thats how it works

Answer (score 3):

Loop through them, check if you've already stored it, if not: add.

```
let $images = $('img');
let uniqueSrc = [];

$images.each(function(){
    if( !uniqueSrc.includes( this.src ) ){
        uniqueSrc.push( this.src );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (no jQuery)

```
let imgs = document.images,
    imgCount = imgs.length,
    src = null,
    urls = [];

for (; imgCount--; ) {
    src = imgs[imgCount].src;
    if (urls.indexOf(src) === -1) {
        urls.push(src);
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/images